# JScrollPane not working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

It's my first time working on Swing. Probably I am doing something seriously wrong.
I have one tabbed UI where each tab is `JPanel` (this tab is added to `JTabbedPane`). I add the number of `JTextField`s in that `JPanel` based on user input. I need that `JPanel` to be scrollable. I have tried following solution:

- Add `Jscrollpane` to `Tab`
- Add new `Jpanel innerPanel` to `JscrollPane`
- Add all textfields to `innerPanel`

There are no textFields displayed.

```
public Tab extends JPanel {

    private TipTailoringTab() {
        JPanel innerPanel =new JPanel();

        int y_cord = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < USER_INPUT; i++) {
                JTextField TextField = new JTextField();
                TextField.setBounds(42, y_cord, 100, 20);
                innerPanel.add(TextField);
                y_cord = y_cord + 40;
        }
        Dimension preferredSize = new Dimension(400, 600);
        innerPanel.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
        JScrollPane sPane = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
        Dimension preferredSize1 = new Dimension(400, 300);
        sPane.setPreferredSize(preferredSize1);
        this.add(sPane);
    }
}
```

Any Help is much appreciated.

EDIT
for every loop I create One TextField, one Slider, On Label. 
I want the following structure vertically scrollable when n is large
TextField1 Slider1 Label1
TextField2 Slider2 Label2

TextFieldn Slidern Labeln

Comment: 1) You'll want to learn how to use the layout managers and use them to their maximal ability. 2) You'll not want to set the bounds of any component, least of all on a JPanel that uses the default FlowLayout. 3) If still stuck, create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Agreeded with Hovercraft, the scoll pane relies heavily on the information generated by the views layout

Comment: I am ready to put in time but I have submission today and this is the only remaining part. Is there is a workaround for current solution ? 
I will revisit and improve my solution.

Comment: How exactly are the textfields supposed to be aligned in the tab?

Comment: TextFields are to be aligned vertically. 
Every Row will have one textfield, one slider and one label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very simple example.  I set the preferred sizes so that it forces the scroll bars to become visible/needed.  Any questions just ask.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    private static final int USER_INPUT = 10;

    public Test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);


        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();
        tabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            tabs.addTab("Tab"+i, new TabPanel());
        }

        frame.add(tabs);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class TabPanel extends JPanel {    
        public TabPanel() {
            JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
            innerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(innerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            for (int i = 0; i < USER_INPUT; i++) {
                JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Label"+i);
                JTextField textArea = new JTextField();
                p.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                p.add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                innerPanel.add(p);
            }

            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
            this.add(scrollPane);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Scrolling is enabled but there is other problem. I want to display one textfield, one slider and one label in each row. Now everything is distorted. All textfields, sliders and labels are in one vertical column.

Comment: Wait what?  So each tab has only one textfield and that textfield is scrollable?  And above the scrollable textfield there is a label?

Comment: Thanks but still labels, textfields are still not in one row and distorted. I tried the setting the dimension as well.

Comment: I made the labels and text areas one above the other.  Change BorderLayout.North/center to west/east.  And I don't know exactly you mean by distorted.